# Unable to pass javascript literal from array values to D3 function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to pass some array values into a d3 scaleLinear function.  The current function looks like this:

```
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d =>
          d.public +
          d.private
        )])
        .range([height, 0]);
```

What I would like to do is pass `d.public` and `d.private` from an array that defines these:

```
const keys = [
      "private",
      "public"
    ]
```

So that I can use them (and pass different keys depending on the data) in the function as:

```
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d =>
          `d.${keys[0]}` +
          `d.${keys[1]}`
        )])
        .range([height, 0]);
```

I've tried several different variations on the syntax above without success.  TIA.

Comment: Try `d[keys[0]]` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string literal to domain rather than values.
`d.${keys[0]}`  translates to 'd.private' and not object.private
Use a function or pass d[keys[0]]..Doing an example for you below with a function ( which gives better flexibility in case you have complex data)

```js
let data = [{
  "private": 10,
  "public": 20
}, {
  "private": 40,
  "public": 30
}, {
  "private": 20,
  "public": 60
}]

const keys = ["private", "public"];
let valueOf = (d, key) => d[key];

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d =>
    valueOf(d, keys[0]) +
    valueOf(d, keys[1])
  )])
  .range([0, 300]);

let points = [0, 12, 45, 34, 77.72, 59.11, 9.99];


d3.select('svg .scal')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(points)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 3)
  .attr('fill', "green")
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return x(d);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg width="400" height="40">
<g class="scal" transform="translate(40, 30)"></g></svg>
</body>
```